# Differential equations with unknown component

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am wondering if there are methods to correct for an unknown component in a (set of) differential equations. It would be useful in the case that one has observations of the system and a (set of) differential equations that partly describe the system.

A simple example: you are given a dataset taken from a system described by the lotka-volterra equations:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha x - \beta  x y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \delta x y - \gamma y$

However, you only have partial knowledge of the dynamics of the system. One of the components (in our case the $-\gamma y$) is unknown. You thus try to fit the following set of equations:

$\frac{dx}{dt} = \alpha x - \beta  x y$

$\frac{dy}{dt} = \delta x y$

This will of course not work as the equations do not fully describe the dynamics of the system.

Are there methods to compensate for this unknown component. Certain machine learning algorithms that are able to estimate this unknown component from the data?

Edit: In this example, it is easy to discover that the $y$-component is missing. However, I am looking for a method that is able to discover all kinds of unknown components (e.g., interaction terms, non-linear components, ...).

Comment: Can't you observe $(\delta xy-dy/dt)/y$ ?

Comment: Indeed, and it would then not be difficult to discover the $y$-component. However, I am looking for a general method, that can discover complex components. I edited the original question to better reflect this.

Comment: I don't think there is a difference between finding missing terms and constructing a model from scratch. Good luck.

Comment: @user44136 . It isn't clear what is known and what is unknown in your question. On what form is the so-called "known" ?. Is it data ? If so, give an example of data.